# How to configure a mouse-wheel dead zone?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

I have a Logitech M525 -- it's a compact portable mouse that uses Logitech's Unifying receivers.   Unlike most other wheel-mice I've owned, it doesn't have a significant detente between "clicks" of the scroll wheel.

That means it's very easy to inadvertently scroll a little bit while middle-clicking -- usually just enough to scroll the *next* link under the cursor.  Very annoying.

Is there any way to configure a mousewheel dead zone in Windows 10 or Ubuntu Unity, so I can ignore very small motions on the scrollwheel?  The alternative is sending this thing to the landfill -- I get annoyed just thinking about it.

Comment: The term you probably want to use is "sensitivity".  (I think software support for that may exist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem (for this Logitech M525) by mechanically increasing the detente strength.

The detente mechanism consists of a pivoting piece of springy wire, pressed against the ridges inside of the mouse wheel.  I was able to bend the wire to get a little more force against the ridges, and the detente is now strong enough to keep the wheel from accidentally scrolling when I try to click.

For good measure, I added a dab of hot-melt on top of the MMB microswitch -- a little less travel is required to actuate, and that really improves the feel of the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

DS-Justice has the solution to the issue here, here are more details.  (by hacking the inside of the mouse and then voiding the warranty...)

So you have to take out 2 screws from under the mouse. These two screws are hidden under the rear plastic flaps that you have to remove. Then you remove the inside cover and 2 batteries, then slide the casing off.

Then you look at the scroll wheel, see a little piece of metal around the scroll wheel, you have to take it out, bend it sideways quite much, then pry it back in position around the plastic mechanism that counts the vertical scrolling, try the wheel, it should be very noisy and respond like a real mechanical mouse wheel.

put back the cover on, put back on the 2 screws, it's good to go.
My solution makes the scroll wheel behave rough instead of smooth.
I guess DS-Justice has a better hack than mine by using some hot glue, but I feel my hack is a safe way for the mouse to behave well during my gaming, but at the price of having a super noisy scrolling wheel.

Comment: fixed. now it does.